# Angular reuse ng-template between project

Tags: angular, ng-template

When I am in child.component, how can I reuse parent.component ng-template? 
I would like reuse the whole ng-template attachmentTemplate, so I do not need to create duplicate code for attachment in child.component again. 
Thank you in advance.

**parent.component.html**

```
<ng-template #attachmentTemplate let-typeId="typeId">   
   <div>Attachments</div>
   <p>{{typeId}}</p>
</ng-template>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="attachmentTemplate; context:{typeId: '2'}"></ng-container>
```

**child.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="attachmentTemplate; context:{typeId: '2'}"></ng-container>
```

Comment: You can simply pass the template variable as input to childcomponent and access... But why do you wanna do this ? can you provide more context ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Can you please write more details? I want to reuse the whole ng-template attachmentTemplate, so I do not need to create duplicate code for attachment in child.component again. Thank you.